# Global exception handling VS Try catch everywhere

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, .net-core, try-catch

Recently I have used Global exception handling in my code and I came to know that with this all exceptions can be handled. Previously I was using try-catch at each controller and now I have removed all the try-catch from controller because of Global exception as it can handle all types of exception.

So I doubt that, is it a good practice to remove all the exception handling I have previously used in the controller for Global Exception handling or should use both Global, as well as try-catch at the controller.

And if try-catch is required, is it necessary that all the exceptions are to be handled at the controller level.

My current working stack is - .Net Core.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can start reading [here](https://code-maze.com/global-error-handling-aspnetcore/#conclusion).

Comment: As a general rule - use global exception handling as little as possible.

Comment: Actually it also depends upon on type of work you are doing like if you are creating API's and you want to return custom error messages on every function instead of generic message like **"something went wrong"** then don't use global exception handler.
But yes global exception handler are sometime important to use where our application scope is too big and on every exception we just need to show user a simple error message. It will save your development time and also reduce code.

Comment: @NaumanKhan, Should we always catch exceptions at the Controller level, what if I catch my exceptions at the business logic layer than to throw it at the controller.

Comment: @BippanSingh yes if you have business logic layer instead of doing everything in controller,you should always catch exception on business logic layer than throw it at controller(with custom messages).

Answer (score 0):

The question is too broad to give a full answer but, let me give my opinion on this matter.

`try-catch-finally` blocks are not used to handle unhandled exceptions. Naturally the cases that you never thought of will be unhandled and you should not keep them silent but you should allow them to express themselves for you to think about them. Handled exceptions though are the cases that are not at the hand of the programmer but he/she has thought about them. For example user input is string instead of number.

If it's the case that you thought but is in your control always check with `if`s. For example if something can be null. Try-catch is really costly and no logic should be handled in them.

Using a global exception handler on the other hand is the exact opossite. It is not to wrap all thought cases and show a single response to user. You should log unknown exceptions to come back and think about why they happened and in the mean time say that you are sorry to user. :)